# Create APK just to extract files without icon or activity

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I'm trying to find a way to create an apk file to extract files to certain path while installing  to use these files in my main app.
In other words I need to add expansion files to my main app by installing another apk that won't be displayed in the launcher.
And play store expansion files is not an option.

Comment: Then you have no solution. Each APK has a name, that name is where the data is stored, and that data is provate to the application which installed it.

Comment: then how some launchers allow you to download themes as apk that you can not open after install and then the theme files appear on the launcher?

Comment: Expansion files.

Comment: does not expansion file need to be downloaded before running the app?

Comment: Nope, a lot of apps download expansions after the initial install. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830667/android-apk-expansion-file-optional

Comment: If you need more info about expansions and how to download then read this: https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: thanks a lot, can you put that as an answer to vote it and close the question?

Comment: @Gusman You *can* access resources of other installed applications through https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getResourcesForApplication(java.lang.String).

Comment: Please explain, what type of files are you referring to. Data? Java classes? Images?

Comment: Mostly images and videos

Comment: Mostly images and videos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is an Expansion file configured as a patch.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830667/android-apk-expansion-file-optional) has some info about it, but you should go to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) about how to download an expansion file after installing your main application.